# How can I run a database query after my test is passed?

Tags: javascript, database, testing, automation

I made automation script with JavaScript and TestaCafe for deleting (setting the item to `disable`) an item. But I want in the end of the test, to execute a query where I can set the deleted item to `enable`, so I don't need to go in the database and execute the query manually.

Comment: Well, I have never used testCafe, but how about creating a new test by copying the script that disables the item, and in the copy change the value to enable and schedule them to run back to back?

Comment: I cant because, once you disable the item you cant enable it from the UI, the only thing you can do, is to enable it from the database. Its not a business scenario for the application to activate a disabled item from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Test Hooks](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/test-code-structure.html#test-hooks) of TestCafe to hook into the lifecycle of a `test` of a `fixture`.

#### In short:

```
fixture.beforeEach(() => {
  // re-enable item here
})
```